# Modular multiplicative inverse in Ruby

Tags: performance, algorithm, ruby, mathematics

I implemented an algorithm to find the modular multiplicative inverse of an integer. The code works, but it is too slow and I don't know why. I compared it with an [algorithm I found in Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#Ruby), which is longer but way faster.

My implementation:

```rb
def modinv1(a, c)
  raise "#{a} and #{c} are not coprime" unless a.gcd(c) == 1
  0.upto(c - 1).map { |b| (a * b) % c }.index(1)
end
```

Rosetta Code's implementation:

> ```rb
> def modinv2(a, m) # compute a^-1 mod m if possible
>   raise "NO INVERSE - #{a} and #{m} not coprime" unless a.gcd(m) == 1
>   return m if m == 1
>   m0, inv, x0 = m, 1, 0
>   while a > 1
>     inv -= (a / m) * x0
>     a, m = m, a % m
>     inv, x0 = x0, inv
>   end
>   inv += m0 if inv < 0
>   inv
> end
> ```

Benchmark results (used `benchmark-ips`):

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
        Rosetta Code   141.248k i/100ms
                Mine   462.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
        Rosetta Code      2.179M (± 6.5%) i/s -     10.876M in   5.022459s
                Mine      4.667k (± 3.7%) i/s -     23.562k in   5.055259s

Comparison:
        Rosetta Code:  2179237.4 i/s
                Mine:     4667.4 i/s - 466.90x  slower
```

Why is mine so slow? Should I use the one I found in Rosetta Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says on the less-obfuscated version on Rosetta Code, their implementation is based on the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Iterative_method_2).  Your implementation works by brute force to test every element in the field, so of course it's going to be slow.